# has been fascinating me

Tags: grammar

is this phrase incorrect : has been fascinating me  ?
because when I had looked on google I came across this example only : has fascinated me !
is fascinate then a stative verb ?

Comment: Just because a dictionary doesn't have an example of the use of every tense of a verb doesn't mean that those tenses can't be used normally. The sentence "His stories of his time in the Amazon have been fascinating me all evening." is perfectly legitimate. To answer the second part of your question it is not a stative verb, but "fascinating" can be used as an adjective which may be misleading you. If we say "The Amazon is a fascinating subject." or "He is a fascinating person." then "fascinating" is being used as an adjective.

Comment: Thank you so much for your helpful comment !

Comment: If it were a stative verb it wouldn't be able to use the progressive; that's only for active verbs: _I am renting that house_ vs *_I am owning that house._